# d3 line chart using path is not showing anything

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to draw a path that means line chart using d3.js. I am using the following code

```
    var data;
d3.csv("myfile.csv",function(datagot){data=datagot;});
var format = d3.time.format("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S");
        data.forEach(function (e){
                e.dist = +e.dist;
                e.speed = +e.speed;
                e.lat=+e.lat;
                e.lon=+e.lon;               
                e.dd=format.parse(e.time);
        });


var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([margin.left, width - margin.right]).domain([d3.min(dataset,function(d){return d.dd}),d3.max(dataset,function(d){ return d.dd})]),
                yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height - margin.top, margin.bottom]).domain([d3.min(dataset,function(d){return d.dist;}),d3.max(dataset,function(d){return d.dist;})]),

                xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xScale).ticks(10).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M")).tickPadding(2),

               yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yScale).orient("left").tickPadding(5).ticks(5);



        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
              .attr("width", width-50 )
              .attr("height", height -60);

              svg.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class","axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);
                // x axis label
                svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", width / 2 )
                .attr("y",  height - 60)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("Time");

                svg.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class","axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left-10) + ",-90)")
                .call(yAxis);

                // Y axis label
                    svg.append("text")
                  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                  .attr("y", 15)
                   .attr("x",70- (height / 2))
                   .attr("dy", "1em")
                   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                   .text("Distance"); 

            // svg.append("g")
              //.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
     var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);
     lineh = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
        return x(d.dd);
             }).y(function(d) {
                return y(d.dist);
    });
        var line  = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (-margin.top) + ")").selectAll(".hour")
              .data(outputf)
              .enter().append("path")
              //.attr("x", function(d) { return (d.dd.getMinutes())*15 ; })
             // .attr("cx", function(d) { return (d.dd.getMinutes())*10 ; })
              //.attr("y", function(d) { return (d.dist)*50 ; })
             // .attr("cy", function(d) { return height-100-(d.dist)*50 ; })
              //.attr("r",3)
/*              .attr("rx", 2)
              .attr("ry", 2)*/
              .attr("d",lineh)
              .attr("class", "line");
```

But its actually not plotting anything. I am giving the jsfiddle for your help to understand. http://jsfiddle.net/1b0gn0r2/. The jsfiddle is not well organized but it contains my code and the csv data I am using is at the bottom. Can anyone help me to find the error?
In my actual code the output is the following
[image]

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for any errors? I see a few potential problems ... the first being that d3.csv is asynchronous. It's likely that your code is being executed before your csv has been loaded and parsed.

Comment: Also, you're binding to `outputf`, which doesn't seem to be defined anywhere else in the code.

Comment: hello in my cide the name of the variable is actually outputf. sorry for confusion. Still it doesn't work

Comment: No error is being shown

Comment: Because a lot of things has changed, use https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245 as an example (2017).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's *a lot* that seems to be wrong in your code! Having various things missing (like `margin`, `height`, `width`, other variables, the CSS etc), makes it very painful to answer your question.

To start with, if you're struggling with jsfiddle you may prefer [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/), which makes it easier to organise your code and data.

I've created a plunk that works with your code here: **http://plnkr.co/edit/ZEi7U6qQ8pxq06FdDIW6?p=preview**

...but it involved quite a few changes, which I'll try to summarise:

**Loading is asynchronous**, so this line:

```
d3.csv("myfile.csv",function(datagot){data=datagot;});
```

will not do what you expect. The rest of the code will go off and execute (eg drawing axes) without `data` having been properly set. So you try to draw the line before the data is ready. Fix this by inserting the main code into the data load function.

**Defining scales**. You seem to define 4 different scales:

- `xScale = d3.time.scale()`
- `yScale = d3.scale.linear()`
- `x = d3.scale.linear()`
- `y = d3.scale.linear()`

That causes problems later in your line drawing function (more to come on that). I've got rid of `x` and `y` here

**The line drawing function** `lineh` expects the scales to be `x` and `y`, but I suggest using the `xScale` and `yScale` ones you've defined before.

```
// line function
lineh = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.dd); // <- do not use d(d.dd)
    })...
```

**Calling the line function** should be done in a completely different way: Your code:

```
var line  = svg.append("g")
    .data(outputf)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d",lineh)
    .attr("class", "line");
```

Not sure what `outputf` is so I ignored that. `lineh` (defines how to draw the line) should be called with the data. I changed the call to:

```
var line = svg.append("g")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", lineh(dataset)) // <- Note the change
    .attr("class", "line");
```

**Finally** I reorganised the code to bring some variable definitions to the top of the file and make it easier to follow.